# Summing up last two digits of all cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have several column and row vectors. All cells are either empty or have a 5 character long entry that ends with a two-digit number: 01, 15, etc.

I want to take all these two digit numbers and sum them up in a simple and easy way.

The current solution is pretty ugly, and looks something like this:

```
=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(K4,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K5,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K6,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K7,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K8,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K9,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K9,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K10,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K11,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K12,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K13,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K14,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K16,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K17,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K18,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K19,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K21,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K22,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K23)),VALUE(RIGHT(K24,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K26,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K27,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K28,2)),VALUE(RIGHT(K29,2)))
```

From experience with other programs I expect there to exist a much simpler solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess the non-empty values could have non-digit characters in the first three positions?

Comment: The first is a digit, the one number 2 and 3 are letters from the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(K4:K29,2))))
```

## Explanation

From https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en

> ### ARRAYFORMULA
>
> Enables the display of values returned from an array formula into
>   multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with
>   arrays